# Code for parenthesis matching using stack made with double linked list isn't giving any output

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, parentheses

I was given an assignment to write the code for parenthesis matching using Double Linked Lists. So, I made stack functions using the same and even wrote the parenthesis matching function with it. But somehow, even after removing all the errors, I'm not able to run the code, i.e. it's not showing any output

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}*top = NULL;

int isFull()
{
    struct node *n = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isEmpty(struct node *top)
{
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

struct node *push(struct node *top, char val)
{
    struct node *ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (isFull())
    {
        printf("Stack overflowed!\n");
    }
    else if (isEmpty(top))
    {
        ptr->data = val;
        ptr->next = top;
        ptr->prev = NULL;
        top = ptr;
        return top;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->data = val;
        top->prev = ptr;
        ptr->next = top;
        ptr->prev = NULL;
        top = ptr;
        return top;
    }
}

char pop(struct node **top)
{
    struct node *ptr = *top;
    char x;
    if (isEmpty(*top))
    {
        printf("Stack Underflowed!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        x = (*top)->data;
        ((*top)->next)->prev = NULL;
        *top = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        return x;
    }
}

void print(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr = start;
    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c ", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int match(char a, char b)
{
    if (a == '{' && b == '}')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a == '[' && b == ']')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a == '(' && b == ')')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int parenthesis(struct node *top, char *str)
{
    char popped_char;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '{' || str[i] == '[' || str[i] == '(')
        {
            top = push(top, str[i]);
        }
        else if (str[i] == '}' || str[i] == ']' || str[i] == ')')
        {
            popped_char = pop(&top);
            if (!match(popped_char, str[i]))
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isEmpty(top))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // struct node *top = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    // top = NULL;
    char *str = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    // printf("%s", str);
    // para(top, str);
    if (parenthesis(top, str))
    {
        printf("Parenthesis Matched!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Parenthesis did not match!\n");
    }
}
```

If I write `{}` or `{()}`, I was expecting to get the output as "Parenthesis did not match!", but my code isn't even running.

Comment: What do you mean with 'is not running'? Do you get any compiler messages?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why would you expect to get output "did not match" for this input? They perfectly match I would say.

Comment: Your implementation of `isFull` does not make sense. You allocate memory and don't use it. That causes a memory leak. Also if you succeeded with allocating it does not mean anything when you want to add a value the next time.

Comment: Your compiler should warn you that you do not return any value from `pop` in some cases.